# Neo4j/Cypher - Multiple WHERE clauses return no results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Queries:

This one returns the expected results:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[pw_rel:PAYED_WITH]->(ext_acc:ExtAccount)
WHERE pw_rel.processed_at > 0
WITH u, COUNT(DISTINCT ext_acc) as accs
WHERE accs > 2
RETURN u
```

While this one doesn't return anything:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[pw_rel:PAYED_WITH]->(ext_acc:ExtAccount)
WITH u, pw_rel, ext_acc, COUNT(DISTINCT ext_acc) as accs
WHERE pw_rel.processed_at > 0 AND accs > 2
RETURN u
```

Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with aggregation, and what it means in the context of other columns. That is, the other non-aggregation columns present act as the grouping key.

In your first query, your only grouping key is u. This means your output is the count of all ext accounts for each user.

In your second query, your grouping key includes u, pw_rel, ext_acc. So it returns the count of all ext accounts for each user / pw-rel / ext_acc combination (or row). That's not very helpful, as you're likely getting back a count of one on each row, so there are no rows that will pass your WHERE clause of the count being > 2. Even if you removed the ext_acc column in your WITH, the pw-rel column would still restrict you to counts of 1 (since there's only one ext_acc per user/pw_rel).

It should be easy to see that the other columns modify what the aggregate functions are grouping on, and the columns you'll get back.

count(ext_acc) - The total count of all ext accounts

u, count(ext_acc) - Users, and the count of ext accounts per user

u, pw_rel, count(ext_acc) - Users, payed-with relations, and the count of all external accounts per User and payed-with relation from that user

u, pw_rel, ext_acc, count(ext_acc) - Users, payed-with relations, ext accounts, and the count of all external accounts per User and payed-with relation from that user to a specific ext account.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!